# What should be the exception guarantee in a (default) constructor that throws?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I know that constructors can throw exceptions and this can be a good thing to do when something bad happens. But when the constructor throws, and assuming that all resources inside constructor are properly managed (for example using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)), which one is the exact exception guarantee (basic, strong)?

In detail, I'm documenting my code and writing the exception guarantees of every member function (and trying of write safe-exception code).

For example, if I have a class like this:

```
struct A
{
    std::string s;

    A()
    {
        std::vector<int> v(5);
        s = "some text";

        /* do a lot of fascinating things */

        if (error)
            throw 1;
    }
};
```

When the constructor throws, destructor of `v` and `s` are called, right? So, thanks to destructors of `std::vector` and `std::string` the constructor of `A` doesn't leak any resources and then it offers at least the basic guarantee. Am I right?

**My question is: Can I say that this constructor offers the strong guarantee?**
Also, is it worth to document the guarantee of constructors?

My guess: it has the strong guarantee indeed. Since the object didn't exist before trying to construct it, and if constructor fails the object won't be created anyway, then the operation (construct the object) has no effect and everything is left just before the constructor started.

If my guess is right:

- when a constructor just offers the basic guarantee and not the strong guarantee?

Comment: _"is it worth to document"_ - All functions should provide exception safety so unless you're planning on writing crappy code you shouldn't need to document this.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious It is not my intention ;) But knowing the actual guarantee of a function is very important since other function could rely on it for its own guarantee. I think is not a bad practice document the exact exception guarantee, but I am not so sure about constructors, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The only objects modified by the constructor are `s` and `v`, and they didn't exist before the constructor was called, and they don't exist after it is exited by an exception either. So there are no observable side effects, and the constructor offers the strong exception guarantee.

When might a constructor offer only the basic guarantee? Possibly contrived example:

```
class A {
  public:
    A() {
        printf("A is being constructed\n");
        throw std::runtime_error("oh no!");
    }
};
```

The basic guarantee is quite obviously upheld, but not the strong guarantee since there is a side effect. (Another way to create a side effect is to modify a global variable.) More interesting things can happen if the constructor takes arguments. Another possibly contrived example:

```
class B {
  public:
    A(std::vector<int>&& v): v(std::move(v)), a() {}
  private:
    std::vector<int> v;
    A a;
};
```

Here, `A`'s constructor throws after `B::v` is already initialized, so the latter is destroyed. The caller still has a valid vector, but it's now empty. The basic guarantee is still satisfied since all objects are in a valid state, but not the strong guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

The strong guarantee requires that if the constructor throws, the (logical) state of the program is not changed (other than that there is an exception to handle). That means that the constructor fulfils the strong exception guarantee if no objects that were passed into it by reference or pointer, global variables and so forth are changed in any fail case (or that any changes that did take place are rolled back before the constructor is left).

The constructor in your example code does not work with any such objects, so it does indeed offer the strong guarantee.

An example of a constructor that offers only the basic guarantee is

```
struct foo {
  foo(int &x) : some_resource(10) {
    ++x;
    if(x % 2 == 0) {
      throw "something";
    }
  }

  std::vector<int> some_resource;
};
```

In this case, the basic guarantee is fulfilled -- `some_resource` is cleaned up in all cases -- but the strong guarantee is not because `x` remains changed if an exception is thrown.

As for documentation, that is kind of a matter of opinion, so YMMV. I would generally aim to provide the strongest guarantee that is reasonably possible, of course, and document that a function fulfills strong or no-throw guarantees if I am certain I can keep this guarantee forever. Documenting the basic guarantee is not necessary because all functions should provide it. A function that does not offer it has a bug.